# WPF + C#/VB Loading assembly from Embedded resource

Tags: .net, wpf, resources, loading

I found several articles discussing "Loading DLL From Embedded Resource" like [this one on Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528178/Load-DLL-From-Embedded-Resource).
They're talking WinForms/Console apps, those have the Main function as app Entry Point. WPF does have Entry Point too, but it's in the file Application.g.i.(vb|cs) which is - as the comment on the top says - automaticly (re)generated.

I'm asking, how to get over it ?
I want: to have just one Executable that have all the required assembies inside, so I can publish just one file & the app won't crash without them (possible in-app check/error handle ?).

**If there's no answer on those questions, then I'm gonna use ILMerge as always.**

**Edit**
Found this article: [How To: Merge assemblies into WPF application](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-merge-assemblies-into-wpf-application), might use it.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this isn't possible.  `ILMerge` is an application that you can use with something like WinForms, but `ILMerge` doesn't support merging WPF assemblies.  See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx) and I got that from the [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) website

Comment: @NETscape "Many people have run into problems using ILMerge for WPF applications because WPF encodes assembly identities in binary resources that ILMerge is unable to modify." I didn't know, damn.

Comment: @Olaf Oh, ok, sorry for confussion of microcontroller fans! :) #ArduinoLove

Comment: If you tried to put me at ease with the arduino-tag: Didn't work. I actually was not aggrevated (hey, I used "please" actually), but as a Arduino-hater, now I might be ....   ;-) - (just kidding)

Comment: @Olaf You're first one that I know (I don't know you lol) that does not like Arduino (wonder why) :/ Still loving it (#ATMega328). Now waiting for Real-Time Clock (Module) && some sensors from Ebay :D

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out in the Edit, there're some articles to look at, if still looking:
[Combining multiple assemblies into a single EXE for a WPF application](http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/61/combining-multiple-assemblies-into-a-single-exe-for-a-wpf-application)
[How To: Merge assemblies into WPF application](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-merge-assemblies-into-wpf-application)

Thanks to @NETscape for pointing out that ILMerge can't be used for same task as with WinForms:

> Many people have run into problems using ILMerge for WPF applications because WPF encodes assembly identities in binary resources that ILMerge is unable to modify. - Mike Barnett (author of ILMerge)